# Using tf.py_func as loss function to implement gradient descent

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm trying to use `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer().minimize(loss)` to get the minimum value of the loss function. But the loss function is very complicated and I need to use numpy to calculate the value, so I use `tf.py_func` to change the output to tensor again and try to use gradient descent to get the result. But this occurs the error: No gradients provided for any variable.

```py
def getvalue(w):
    return w

train_X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

train_Y = np.array([34,56,78,27,96])

X = tf.placeholder("float")

Y = tf.placeholder("float")

w = tf.Variable([0.0,0,0,0,0], name="weight")
loss = tf.py_func(getvalue,[w],tf.float32)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.02).minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    temp = 1
    for i in range(100):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            _, w_value = sess.run([train_op, w],feed_dict={X: x,Y: y})
        temp += 1
```

Here's a very simple loss function, but when compile it still occurs No gradients provided for any variable.
So is there's a way to solve it? Do I need to calculate everything in tensor in order to use gradient descent?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include relevant code parts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've added the relevant code parts.

Comment: This means basically that your loss function is not differentiable. Please provide complete code for loss function, so that we could see what could be done